# Toolbar анимация

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Реализуя свою программу, я хотел сделать так, что бы Toolbar исчезал по нажатию. Все хорошо, он исчезает, но делает это резко. А я хочу что бы исчезновение было плавным, как в ActionBar. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Toolbar это обычный View, используйте для его исчезновения любую стандартную анимацию, которую применяют к любым View.

Comment: Нет. Если устанавливать toolbar, как supportActionBar, то нельзя вызывать анимацию для негоъ

Answer (score 2):

Как заметили в комментариях для ActionBar нужно включать анимацию, которая не включена по умолчанию. Используйте код:

```
actionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(boolean enabled);
```